# image upload design not working when label is ahead of input tag

Tags: html, css

I found the tutorial/article regarding the custom file upload design. There he has used label just beneath input tag but in my case the label is ahead of input tag and I can't adjust the label to bring down of the input tag as I am using django for server side where the form is rendered using DRY principle. I have created the jsfiddle but the code is not mine. The code and concept is from the following link

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

Here is the jsfiddle demo

https://jsfiddle.net/b7rmwhnf/

Here is the code

```css
.inputfile {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.inputfile+label {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #598C93;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.inputfile:focus+label,
.inputfile+label:hover {
  background-color: #598C93;
}

.inputfile+label {
  cursor: pointer;
  /* "hand" cursor */
}

.inputfile+label:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f093";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inputfile+label * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
<label for="file">Choose a file</label>

<label for="file">Choose a file</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
```

Comment: So... you want the label to be **underneath** the input? I'm not sure I understand what you're wanting to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works due the [+ selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) which in your case, styles the `label` which goes AFTER the `input`...

Unfortunately there is no 'previous' selector in CSS.

Comment: Can't I then achieve the desired result with the label being in front of the input tag?

Comment: No, you can't unfortunately as there is no such selector.

Comment: Thank you. I had to change my widget styling